# Get Average TimeSpan from a Group

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

I need to retrieve an average TimeSpan from a List of grouped objects, but have no idea where to start.

Each object in the list has a property of type TimeSpan and I've grouped the List by another property. Now I need the average TimeSpan from each group.

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
Item _item1 = new Item { Category = "A", Duration = _someTimeSpan1};
Item _item2 = new Item { Category = "B", Duration = _someTimeSpan2};
Item _item3 = new Item { Category = "A", Duration = _someTimeSpan3};
Items.Add(_item1);
Items.Add(_item2);
Items.Add(_item3);

var _groupedItems = Items.GroupBy(i => i.Category);
```

In the above example _item1 and _item3 are grouped on Category and I need the average of Duration for those two items that are in the group.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What approaches have you come up with? Why did they not work?

Comment: As I said, I have no idea where to start. I've gotten as far as grouping the items by Category, but I don't know how to access the Duration property just for items in an individual group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var group in _groupedItems) {
   var avg = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(group.Average(i => i.Duration.TotalSeconds));
}
```

Comment: I chained this onto the initial query as in the other reply, but ultimately used your code to get the average from the group.

Answer (score 2):

```
var _groupedItems = Items.GroupBy(i => i.Category)
    .Select(g => new { Cat = g.Key, 
    Avg = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt64(g.Select(x=>x.Duration.Ticks).Average())) });
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
foreach (var group in _groupedItems){
    Console.WriteLine(group.Average(g => g.Duration.TotalMilliseconds));
}
```